# is it okay to have two material apps in one flutter?

Tags: flutter

**I added two material app to my app because my futurebuilder needed a context and my provider was not accessible to the other classes i created. is it an acceptable practice???**

```
runApp(
        MaterialApp(
            title: 'register app',
            home: FutureBuilder(
              future: Hive.openBox('store'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                  else
                    return MultiProvider(providers: [
                      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                        value: form_entry(),
                      )
                    ], child: MyApp());
                } else
                  return Scaffold(
                      body: Center(
                    child: Text('error error ooops error'),
                  ));
              },
            )),
      );[enter image description here][1]

// my app class has another material app

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: home_screen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of a [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget is to provide a common theme setting based on Material design and configures the root navigator for all of its children widgets.

In order to avoid conflicting, you should **only have 1 MaterialApp**. In your case, you can call the `openBox()` method without using the `FutureBuilder` by calling it within the `main()` method:

```dart
void main() async {
  // Include this line to make sure WidgetsFlutterBinding is initialized, since
  // we're using main() asynchronously
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Open the Hive box here
  var box = await Hive.openBox('store');

  // Then run the app
  runApp(
        MaterialApp(
            title: 'register app',
            home: MultiProvider(providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                value: form_entry(),
              )
            ], child: home_screen());
        )
    );
```

**Small note**: When creating new class or method in Dart, best practice is to use CamelCase. So `form_entry()` should be named `FormEntry()` for Class name or `formEntry()` for Method name. Same goes with `home_screen()`. You can refer to the [styling guide here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-types-using-uppercamelcase)

Comment: Hey, I have the same question, but with StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder, so that i can show Login screen when user logs out from the application, how do i do this when await cannot work in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is older post but I personally do use 2 MaterialApps.

I have my main App() inside MultiBlocProvider which provides only the AuthenticationBloc and RegistrationBloc and based on AuthenticationState I return specific MaterialApp for that state.

For example, when user is Authenticated, I return 'main' MaterialApp which is wrapped in additional 10-15 BlocProviders (with MultiBlocProvider and separate navigatorKey alongside all of the named routes which are for the Authenticated user

For UnAutheticated state, I return 2nd MaterialApp which is not wrapped in additional BlocProviders but only has access to the single '/' route and/or unauthenticated routes and only to main 2 Blocs which are Registration and AuthenticationBloc.

I return them from BlocBuilder withon main App() widget and returning them with the Builder()

I am not sure if this is the best and even good approach but it works very well.

I had issue where I wanted my existing Bloc-s to conpletely destory when user logsOut so I decided to move them.completely out of the widget tree. Along that, all of my BlocProviders have default event which is called during Bloc initialization so when you logout, and login with dofferent user, there is no place for any issues with old Blocs still being inited from.previous user.

Also, if there is any senior flutter dev which could comment my approach that I used I would gladly listen.

Answer (score -2):

It's bad to have two MaterialApp() widgets, at least one in other.

I did that by mistake, I thought I do not have one and added an extra one. Then the app randomly crashed on hot restart, sit one whole day to debug everything and haven't found what crashed my app, then I started to refactor code and found I have two `MaterialAapp`, one in `StatelessWidget` and one in `home` widget that was on different file. After removing it my app stopped randomly crashing.

Never use two, atleast not one in other.

Comment: You can have two Material App if you know what you're doing, though it's not recommended (Flutter won't complain though). Google search engine happen to pick your answer which was misleading a bit as I initially thought it's something I should never tried after looking at your answer.